# kotlin Why can't conditional control overload methods?

Tags: android, kotlin, operator-overloading

I think this should work in theory, and I've spent a lot of time doing so.

Here is an example of my code.

```kotlin
//code sample
fun sample(s1:String){
    //...
}

fun sample(i1:Int){
    //...
}

// I want to...

val str = "Hello"
val i = 00865

sample(if (str != "Hello") i else str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin is a statically typed language; i.e., each expression must evaluate to a particular type at compile time (one and only one).

> `sample(if (str != "Hello") i else str)`

Here, the conditional is an Expression in Kotlin, it should yield to a single type, but How?

- The `if` branch returns an int (`i`),
- The else branch returns a String (`str`).

So, these are two different types; but the compiler is smart enough to consider both as of type `Any` giving you the warning:

> **"Conditional branch result of type Int/String is implicitly cast to Any"**

Note that: Every Kotlin class has `Any` as a super class.

But, that won't compile as well, because you don't have a `sample` method that takes in [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) type.

One way to fix this to have that overload version:

```
 fun sample(a: Any){
   //...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, luckily I have stopped that behavior a few hours ago

Answer (score 2):

Which method is called is determined when the code is compiled. You are trying to determine the method at runtime.

In your code since the two types are incompatible (String and Int) the compile assumes that the type is `Any` - hence there is no valid method for it to call - so it won't compile.

The following example may make it clearer:

```
fun sample(n: Int) {
    println("$n is Int")
}

fun sample(n: Number) {
    println("$n is Number")
}

fun callSample() {
    val a: Int = 4
    val b: Number = a

    sample(a)
    sample(b)
}
```

Even though the same number (4) is passed to both methods the output will be:

```
4 is Int
4 is Number
```

Because the compiler uses the type of the variable to determine the method.

Comment: Thank you, luckily I have stopped that behavior a few hours ago